# Adding special characters between rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a list of lists like this:

Input:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
abc = [a,b,c]
abc
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

And I convert it into a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = abc, columns = ['a','b','c'])
```

To get a table like this:

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

How would I put a special character (Like ! or #) between each list (so each row)?

Pretty much what I want is this:

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
!   !   !
4   5   6
!   !   ! 
7   8   9
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think something like this would actually be useful?

Comment: You can look into the prettytable, texttable, termtable or tabulate package if you want a data frame to be formatted differently in the shell.

Comment: @DavidErickson This is not my question so I cannot set accept a solution for it. Try asking taliamycota

Comment: @DavidErickson All good. No need to apologize :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a brute force way but simple to understand is to create a new dataframe from the existing dataframe and set each column to `!`. Then, append to the original dataframe and sort by the index:

```
df1 = df.copy()
for col in df1.columns: df1[col] = '!'
df.append(df1).sort_index().iloc[:-1]
Out[1]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
0  !  !  !
1  4  5  6
1  !  !  !
2  7  8  9
```

If you want a new index without duplicate values, you could also do:

```
df.append(df1).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-1]

    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   !   !   !
2   4   5   6
3   !   !   !
4   7   8   9
```

Answer (score 2):

If your index is the default range index, then you can use something like np.linspace.

```
df.reindex(np.linspace(0,df.index.max(),df.index.max()*2+1)).fillna('!').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  !  !  !
2  4  5  6
3  !  !  !
4  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = abc, columns = ['a','b','c'],index=range(0,len(abc)*2,2))
df = df.reindex(range(len(abc)*2)).fillna('!')
```